# How do I find the set $U$ on which this series defines a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have just come across a question that asks me to find the set $U$ on which this series defines a holomorphic function. I have trawled through my notes but I can't find anything, any help on how I would go about doing it would be greatly appreciated
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2n}$$

Comment: Hint: Where is the power series convergent?

Comment: the radius of convergence is 2 so for $|z|<2$ ?

Comment: The usual ratio test does it.

Comment: The radius of convergence is not 2, but you seem to have the right idea.

Comment: The radius of convergence is $1$, not $2$.

Comment: so theset $U$ i which the series defines a holomorphic function is for all $|z|<1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that a convergent power series converges to a holomorphic function in the interior of the region of convergence, then it's a matter of finding the region in which the series converges.  The ratio test proceeds as follows:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{z^{n+1}/(2(n+1))}{z^n/(2n)}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} |z|\frac{n}{n+1} = |z|.
$$
So the series converges to a holomorphic function within the disk $|z|<1$.

Comment: fantastic thank you very much!